# Is this JSON oddball ? - SwiftyJSON

Tags: swift, ibm-cloud, swifty-json

I got the unusual json (actually from IBM Bluemix), shown below,

Thank goodness, trusty and heartwarming SwiftyJSON was able to get the values, like this...

```
let mauves = json["blue"][0]["brown"][0]["mauve"]
```

However, notice there are weird sort of "empty unnamed array nested things" in the JSON (hence the `[0]` calls to Swifty).

My question, in short,

is this valid json?

Even if valid, is it "crappy"?  Or am I wrong, it's totally idiomatic?  (Maybe I've just been dating the wrong services for decades, I don't know.)

I appreciate that running it through online validators seems to say "valid" (except this one http://json.parser.online.fr gives red things), but, you know, who trusts online services?  Ask experts on SO....)

```
--
{
  "red" : 1,
  "green" : 4,
  "blue" : [
    {
      "yellow" : "word",
      "brown" : [
        {
          "orange" : "1826662593",
          "gold" : "23123",
          "mauve" : [
            {
              "a" : "Beagle",
              "b" : 0.979831
            },
            {
              "a" : "Chow",
              "b" : 0.937588
            },
            {
              "a" : "Hound",
              "b" : 0.987798
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
--
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON is valid. The `blue` member contains an array with `1` element (at index `[0]` which is the `yellow` object, and this is repeated for `orange`.

When I paste it into json.parser.online.fr it reports it as valid for me - are you accidentally including other text around it?

Comment: Really, the `[0]` is the way to get that ?  It seems weird, but I don't know another way.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON is perfectly valid - your validators are not lying to you.  I don't know if this JSON contains real keys, or if the names have been changed to protect the innocent (it certainly looks like nonsense), but in a real world situation there are frequently arrays that contain one element (because they *might* contain zero or many elements!).

Comment: Thanks man, nicely explained.  Good one.  You really think the `[0]` is the best way to get that ??

Comment: Yes, it is.  It's a pretty standard way of retrieving the first element of a zero-indexed array I'd say.  What services have you been dating...?  Don't worry, we'll get you back on your feet.